# GPU invidia error failed to import supplied dmabufs

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've updated my GPU driver from 470 to 535 and then I can't run my alacritty with error

```
[destroyed object]: error 7: failed to import supplied dmabufs: Arguments are inconsistent (for example, a valid context requires buffers not supplied by a 
[1]    4835 segmentation fault (core dumped)  alacritty
```

then I reinstall to 470 but I still have this error.
`prime-select` to inter (from nvidia) helps me, but I belive there is solution for whole system

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem (not sure what's the source of problem, maybe driver update, but not sure)

Comment: @user214717 Firstly, I prefer to stay on nvidia-525 on two of my devices, because 535 trigger a lot of bugs.
This helps me to fix it
export `__EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES=/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json`
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/103999